# Custom field in Sales Quote Item

Tags: event-observer, magento-1, quote

I have added a custom field in Quote item table. I have been able to populate this field and can see data in it. However, during conversion from Quote to Order I am trying to retrieve value of this field for current item. I am doing this in Observer. Added an observer event sales_convert_quote_item_to_order_item and code for getting field value is like this:

```
$quoteItem = $observer->getItem();

$customFieldData = $quoteItem->getCustomFieldData();
```

This is not working. It seems that $observer->getItem() returns model Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Item, so my custom field is not present in this model.

Comment: you need to retrieve the value or just pass it on to the order item?

Comment: I need to get the value.

Comment: @Marius if this is not possible, is it possible to loop on Quote items and get the value and somehow determine which order item and quote item are related. I can see that below code works:  `foreach ( $quote->getAllVisibleItems() as $_item )
        {
              $intrepiaData = $_item->getCustomFieldData();
        }`  Is there a field to determine which order line item is related to quote line item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue resolved, used following code to get custom field data:
`$quoteItem = $observer->getItem();
$customData = $quoteItem->getQuoteItem()->getCustomFieldData();`